# What kind of beetle is this? Beneficial or Pest?

Tags: identification, insects

This beetle was found on napa cabbage.  It doesn't look like it's feeding off the napa cabbage.  Not sure if I should let it go to backyard where the veggie beds.  Is this a beneficial or pest?  Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Scarab guest is an adult Spotted Grapevine Beetle, Southern Variant, *Pelidnota* *punctata*, and they generally dine on wild & domestic grapes & grape leaves, and generally arenot a serious pest of grapes. The adults are about 25-28mm in length, and the grubs/ larvae, which feed on rotting wood and live underground for a year, grow to 45-50mm long. They're fairly strong flyers, and you might sometimes see them around lights at night. They're found in Central to Southern Eastern North America. They may be very mildly pesty, but the grubs are mildly beneficial. Good question and good clear illustration! Your Scarab guest should be fine in the backyard (unless you're growing grapes), and grubs could be beneficial by consuming rotting underground wood.